# Find first empty seat in an 2d array list

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, methods

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    boolean[][] aud = { { true, true, true, true }, // rad 0
            { false, false, true, false }, // rad 1
            { true, false, true, true }, // rad 2
            { true, true, true, true }, // rad 3
    };


public static void firstEmptySeat(boolean[][] array) {
    
    
    String a = "";
    
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
            
            if (array[i][j] == false) {
                
                a = i + "," + j;
            }
        }
        
    }
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

Me and my friend are trying to find the first empty seat in a 2d array called aud. False matches to an empty seat. We are supposed to print out the first empty seat in the array, and its index, but our code only gives us the last empty seat. Can anyone help?

Comment: Add a break within the if statement to break out of the for loop as soon as you find your first empty seat. Here is a reference: https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_break.asp

Comment: Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a break statement when the condition is fulfilled. And for the outer loop, you can use a flag.

```
public static void firstEmptySeat(boolean[][] array) {
    
    
    String a = "";
    bool flag = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
            
            if (array[i][j] == false) {
                
                a = i + "," + j;
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(flag == false)
           break;
    }
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

Comment: Will need to break from the outer loop as well.  Probably easier to just return.